# Combination of Maxwell equations and other form of Maxwell equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

In reference to [this paper on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506035), page three, we have the following:

We know that the Bianchi Identites are $\partial_{[\alpha F_\beta\gamma]} = 0$
 and are equivalent to

$$\nabla \cdot B =0 $$
$$\nabla \times E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$

We also know that  given a Lagrangian $L$ one may define $G^{\mu\nu}$ by:
$$G^{\mu\nu} = -2 \frac{\partial L}{\partial F_{\mu\nu}}$$

and equivalently,

$$\nabla \cdot D =0 $$
$$\nabla \times H = +\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}$$

The field equations and Bianchi identites may be combined in the form

$$\nabla \cdot (D +iB) =0 $$

$$ \nabla \times (E +iH) = i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (D+iB)$$

My question is the last line, how were these combined based on what's before?

Comment: Split into real and imaginary parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Holographer's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150609/combination-of-maxwell-equations-and-other-form-of-maxwell-equations#comment314072_150609) points out, what one does is the following: First, multiply the equations with $B$ and $H$ on the left hand side by $i$:
$$i\nabla\cdot B=\nabla\cdot(iB)=0,\hspace{1cm} \text{and}\hspace{1cm}\nabla\times (iH)=\frac{\partial( iD)}{\partial t} $$ 
The key observation is that the divergence and curl do not mix real and imaginary components. Now, we simply sum the equations pairwise to obtain the required result:

$$\nabla \cdot (D +iB) =0 $$

$$ \nabla \times (E +iH) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (iD-B)=i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(D+iB)$$
Note that these two equations are *equivalent* to Maxwell's equations: Because the derivatives don't mix the real and imaginary parts, they must vanish independently.

Comment: thank you for your nice answer. I have one question though, why would one do that? I mean why combine these two equations with one another? And why did we use the imaginary number "i"? Is their some physical interpretation behind this?

Comment: @Fluctuations you should continue reading the paper to find out why one would do this...